# This is a legal way to initialize an array. But how would I access its elements?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I am preparing for the entry-level Oracle certification - OCA - Java Programmer I, since they require people to take this one before taking the next one (used to be possible to just go for SCJP directly, which is equivalent of OCP - Java Programmer II)

I came across this question on array initialization, that got me a bit puzzled. Obviously, one can declare and initialize an array like this:

```
Object[] objects = { new Object[1], new Object[34] };
```

as the arrays are objects, you can stick object arrays into an object array. You can easily get at one or the other object array by doing `objects[0]` or `objects[1]` but where would you go from there? How would you access the, say, 16th Object from the object array stored under `objects[1]`?

Basically, my question can be simplified to this:

```
Object o = new Object[100];
```

The above compiles. However, how would one access individual objects in the Object array `o`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `Object[]` is also an `Object`, which is why your declaration

```
Object o = new Object[100];
```

works.<sup>*</sup> To access the elements, though, you need to cast it back to an `Object[]`. For example:

```
Object elt = ((Object[]) o)[3];
```

For your original declaration:

```
Object[] objects = { new Object[1], new Object[34] };
```

you will have to do a similar thing to access the 16th element of `objects[1]`:

```
Object elt = ((Object[]) (objects[1]))[15];
```

Of course, you can avoid all this casting by declaring:

```
Object[][] objects = { new Object[1], new Object[34] };
```

in the first place. Then you can just do `objects[1][15]`.

<sup>*</sup> Note that this is true only of `Object`, which has special status as the root of the object hierarchy in Java. An `Integer[]` cannot be assigned to an `Integer` variable.

Comment: ahhh... stupid me. A cast is all that is needed. I understand all the rest.

Answer (score 5):

You'd have to cast it back to `Object[]`:

```
    Object o = new Object[] {new String("abc"), null, new Integer(1)};
    Object[] arr = (Object[]) o;
    Object elem = arr[0];
    System.out.println(elem);
```

This prints `abc`.

It works because `System.out.println()` is happy to take an `Object`. If it required a `String`, you'd need another downcast.